# Rails 5 HABTM from multiple databases works in mysql command but error in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am building an rails 5 app that connects to 2 different databases (dbA & dbB). My databases are on the same database host.

I want to make a wishlist. Pretty easy when using the same DB, but I am stuck with an "interesting" error.

This is what the databases look like:

[image]

the models are as follow:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :wishlist, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**wishlist.rb**

```
class Wishlist < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  # has_and_belongs_to_many :wines
  # The above did not work
  # so I had to revert to has_many through
  has_many :wines_wishlists
  has_many :wines, through: :wines_wishlists
end
```

**wines_wishlist.rb**

```
class WinesWishlist < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :wine
  belongs_to :wishlist

  def self.table_name_prefix
    "dbA_#{Rails.env}."
  end
  # I added the above to prevent ActiveRecord from
  # looking for the table in the wrong database
end
```

**wine.rb (legacy model)**

```
class Wine < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection LEGACY_DB 
  # LEGACY_DB is the legacy database connection info from a yaml file
  # located in config.

  def self.table_name_prefix
    "dbB_#{Rails.env}."
  end
end
```

This is quite straigth forward IMHO. Now the interresting error:

When I try the following :

```
user = User.last
user.wishlist.wines
```

It works on my local machine in development. It doesn't work on my staging server! When I try in the rails console, I get this:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'dbA_staging.wines_wishlists' doesn't exist: SELECT  `dbB_staging`.`wines`.* FROM `dbB_staging`.`wines` INNER JOIN `dbA_staging`.`wines_wishlists` ON `dbB_staging`.`wines`.`id` = `dbA_staging`.`wines_wishlists`.`wine_id` WHERE `dbA_staging`.`wines_wishlists`.`wishlist_id` = 1
```

This is the expected SQL.

```
user.wishlist.wines.to_sql
=> "SELECT  `dbB_staging`.`wines`.* FROM `dbB_staging`.`wines` INNER JOIN `dbA_staging`.`wines_wishlists` ON `dbB_staging`.`wines`.`id` = `dbA_staging`.`wines_wishlists`.`wine_id` WHERE `dbA_staging`.`wines_wishlists`.`wishlist_id` = 1"
```

Even better, when I try the same SQL in `rails db` on my staging machine, it works!! It doesn't work in rails even though the SQL is correct, but it works in mysql command line.

I based my code on the [following article](http://emphaticsolutions.com/2009/11/23/has_many_through_across_databases.html) and made [some research](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21113), but I can't seem to figure out how to go around this problem.

I am using (same for development and staging):

- Rails 5.1.1
- ruby 2.4.0p0
- mysql 5.6.34 (staging)
- mysql 5.7.17 (development)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Taking a look at the article you linked to, it seems to be using a gem [`st-elsewhere`](https://github.com/briandoll/st-elsewhere), i.e.

```
has_many_elsewhere :wines, :through => :wines_wishlist
```

Also, as stated in the article, you can't make `JOIN` queries across database connections. The gem circumvents this using some less efficient queries, the details of which I did not look up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think the article says that for two database on the same host, there is no need of gem, and as I say in my question, it works on development, but for some reason not on staging.

Comment: Ah. Then that would suggest some mismatch between your development and staging environments. You're sure that all the databases and tables are identical between the environments?

Comment: Identical. And as I said, on the staging server, it works in mysql command line, but not in rails, despite outputting same SQL.

Comment: It seems I made some hasty assumptions. If you're sure the exact same SQL output works in the db cli but not when called via `ActiveRecord`, I'm at loss.

Comment: Then that's the two of us :)! Thanks for your help!